# Singularity at inifnity?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is a necessary and sufficient condition for the function $f(z)$ to have a removable singularity at $\infty$ for $f(1/z)$ to have a removable singularity at $0$. Does the same hold for any other type of singularity (e.g. poles, essential singularities, non-isolated singularities etc.) and can this be proven?

Comment: A conformal mapping of a neighbouthood of $\infty$ to a neighbourhood of $0$ (or between any other two points of the Riemann sphere)) preserves the type of singularity.